# How can I create this excel formula in tableau?

Tags: excel, formula, tableau-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSdBD.png)

I want to calculate the percentage part in tableau.

I tried Total([name of the table])/ ([february])
and also creating several calculated fields and trying to divide it individually.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWREp.png)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume the $ column in your picture is `[sales]` (and that it is a continuous(green) measure) in Tableau and I am also assuming you have some `[date]` column where you are pulling your months from.

Drag your `[date]` pill to rows and and choose a discrete(blue) month aggregation. Drag `[sales]` to rows too, right click `[sales]` and choose *Discrete*. Again grab `[sales]` and drag it you your Text marks (between data pane and worksheet canvas), it should be a green(continuous) pill, right click it and choose *Quick Table Calculation -> Percent of Total* .

To get the totals, go to Analysis in the top toolbar Select *Totals -> Add totals for rows* or select the Analytics tab(next to your data pane tab) and drag the *Totals* pill into your viz canvas.

Comment: P.S. When you use a table calc, like Percent of Total, you also have to specify percent of “which” total. Tableau will take a good guess what you mean, but if it isn’t what you’re looking for, right click on the pill and try the different “Compute Using” options to find the one you want